# Remane uploaded file jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload, blueimp

I am using blueimp jquery file upload. Is there any way to rename the uploaded document. I would also like to change the upload directory. I am using the mini ajax file uploader.

http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

Comment: blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: You should have some server code which handles the uploaded file. You should be able to rename the file there.

Comment: We are doing that once the file is uploaded. I am having and issue when I upload a captured picture. The device names them all the same (image.jpg). I was trying to change the name at this point. It could be as simple as date stamp.

Answer (score 0):

No, for security reasons you can't do this on the client side. You can rename the file on the server when it gets uploaded.